# How to get rendered HTML using handlebar express?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

```
 res.render('emp-template',employees);
```

Instead of above code, how can I assign the rendered HTML to a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render) accepts an optional callback, which is passed error and html string arguments.

Answer (score -1):

More specifically

```
    res.render("partials/mail-to-client",(err,html)=>{
      console.log(html);
      res.json(true);
    })
```